# Sending internal emails

Tags: php, sendmail, swiftmailer

**CODE:**

```
$from = $_GET['from'];
$to = $_GET['to'];
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to, 'PHP mail() function', 'Coming from PHP mail() function', $headers);
echo 'Check your inbox for PHP mail() function';
```

Code above used to work for sending local emails but not anymore. Only works for sending external email. Also, swift_emailer() doesn't work either.

**MORE DETAILS:**

**Located at:**

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail
```

**phpinfo() output:**

```
sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

**MAIL LOG:**

```
Mar 21 12:18:27 database sendmail[15156]: r2LCEFfB015154: to=<myaddress@whateveritis.com>, ctladdr=<apache@localhost.localdomain> (48/48), delay=00:04:12, xdelay=00:04:12, mailer=esmtp, pri=120357, relay=mx00.1and1.co.uk. [212.227.15.134], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Mar 21 12:18:27 database sendmail[15156]: r2LCEFfB015154: r2LCIRfB015156: DSN: Service unavailable
Mar 21 12:18:27 database sendmail[15156]: r2LCIRfB015156: to=root, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=31619, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Mar 21 12:18:32 database sendmail[15162]: r2LCENGr015160: to=<myaddress@whateveritis.com>, ctladdr=<apache@localhost.localdomain> (48/48), delay=00:04:09, xdelay=00:04:08, mailer=esmtp, pri=120356, relay=mx01.1and1.co.uk. [212.227.17.175], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Mar 21 12:18:32 database sendmail[15162]: r2LCENGr015160: r2LCIWGr015162: DSN: Service unavailable
Mar 21 12:18:32 database sendmail[15162]: r2LCIWGr015162: to=root, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=31618, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Mar 21 12:18:50 database sendmail[15166]: r2LCEk12015164: to=<myaddress@whateveritis.com>, ctladdr=<apache@localhost.localdomain> (48/48), delay=00:04:04, xdelay=00:04:04, mailer=esmtp, pri=120357, relay=mx01.1and1.co.uk. [212.227.15.134], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Mar 21 12:18:50 database sendmail[15166]: r2LCEk12015164: r2LCIo12015166: DSN: Service unavailable
Mar 21 12:18:50 database sendmail[15166]: r2LCIo12015166: to=root, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=31619, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Mar 21 12:19:39 database sendmail[15229]: r2LCJcKD015229: from=apache, size=123, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201303211219.r2LCJcKD015229@localhost.localdomain>, relay=apache@localhost
Mar 21 12:19:39 database sendmail[15230]: r2LCJdfM015230: from=<apache@localhost.localdomain>, size=357, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201303211219.r2LCJcKD015229@localhost.localdomain>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]
Mar 21 12:19:39 database sendmail[15229]: r2LCJcKD015229: to=myaddress@whateveritis.com, ctladdr=apache (48/48), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30123, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (r2LCJdfM015230 Message accepted for delivery)
```

Comment: What happens when you try? Does the message vanish? Do you get a bounce message from a mail server? Are there any errors? What does your HTTP server log say? What does your sendmail log say?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you change the `$from` to an external email address, will it work? Have you checked SPAM folders?

Comment: @Quentin - No error, no bouce, log added above.

Comment: @Asok - Nothing changes, spam folder is empty.

Comment: 1) Could you name your OS release? [It may help (at least to make difference between MTA and MSA log entries)] 2) Could you post **ALL** log entries with r2LCJdfM015230?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked with your hosting company to see if they implemented an internal mail system on the server? Something that would be catching the mail and delivering it locally and not letting it leave the server? If you check your directory, it's oftentimes a folder like //Mail or something similar.

Comment: Just found out that they have a buggy rule or whatever it is that stops normal incoming and outgoing mails. Works now.

Comment: @MadMax, I've got the same problem. Can you please elaborate on how you came to a solution?

Comment: @zbinsd - Sorry I've just seen your message. The hosting company sorted it out on their end I haven't realy done anything. I hope you already sorted it anyway.